# Changing values of CPU registers under GNU/Linux

Tags: c

Is it possible to change values of CPU registers under GNU/Linux with help of C programming language code?

Comment: One of the purposes of higher-level languages is to abstract away the hardware. May I ask *why* you want to do it? What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is your use-case?

Comment: C code constantly changes registers in the CPU. Thus very silly answer would be "yes". You just can't determine what is changed to what...

Comment: This is obviously just trolling:(

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: Using standard C then no it's not possible.

But some compilers have extensions to allow you to write *inline assembler*. Also, you can write your own assembler files and have functions that can be called from your C source in them. Use an assembler to create object files that you link with the rest of your program.